# after changing documentroot, xampp still using default phpmyadmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I used XAMPP to install Apache, PHP, MySQL.

I then personalized the `c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file thusly:

```
# DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\edward\Documents\webs"

# <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
<Directory "C:\Users\edward\Documents\webs">
```

I now can put websites e.g. here:

```
C:\Users\edward\Documents\webs\test
```

which map here:

```
http://localhost/test/
```

However, when copied in my own phpmyadmin site here:

```
C:\Users\edward\Documents\webs\phpmyadmin
```

I noticed that the URL:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

still points to:

```
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
```

Where is this being set and how can I change it so that the URL `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` maps to `C:\Users\edward\Documents\webs\phpmyadmin`?

Comment: You should have a look at the aliases. Maybe there's an alias which points to the default phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4):

It's because xampp uses an `alias` for pointing `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` to `xampp's phpmyadmin path`

So what you can do is, find `Alias /phpmyadmin` in your `httpd.conf` and replace it with `Alias /xphpmyadmin` or even `Alias /phpmyadmin2`. If you do this, you will not have conflict with having a `phpmyadmin` folder in your `webs` folder.

Answer (score 2):

This may help others You will find the lines in your httpd.conf file

> `# XAMPP specific settings
>
>   Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"`

If you look in the included file "httpd-xampp.conf" you will see the line

> ```
> Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
> <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
>     AllowOverride AuthConfig
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

Modifying this information in any number of ways (change httpd-xampp.conf, include your own custom conf file, placing a statement after the above statements) should solve your problem